# SQL | Get products and product variants

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I got the following mysql structure:

```
`product`
id  |   name        |   quantity    | unit
10  |   Color bath  |   12          |   L
20  |   Color house |   15          |   L

`product_variant`
id  |   masterid    |   name        |   quantity    |   unit
100 |   10          |   Color bath  |   10          |   L
200 |   10          |   Color bath  |   20          |   L
300 |   20          |   Color house |   20          |   L
```

What our query should return:

Give me all products and give me all productvariants from this product and return for each product / product_variant a line:

```
product.id as masterid, product.id/product_variant.id, product.name, product.quantity/product_variant.quantity, product.unit/product_variant.unit
10, 10, Color bath, 12, L
10, 100, Color bath, 10, L
10, 200, Color bath, 20, L
20, 20, Color house, 15, L
20, 300, Color house, 20, L
```

We tried it using a UNION SELECT but this seems to be not the right solution. It takes up to 2 seconds for 10.000 rows (with using indexes).
Is there any other chance to get what we need without using UNION?

Answer (score 0):

I don't that what you are trying to do is possible without an `UNION` because you need to join the two tables `product` and `product_variant` and when you join them you'll get (as in your example) two rows for `product.id = 10` no more no less, while you are expecting 3.